# Gmail account contacts

Tags: google-contacts

I am able to receive emails on my phone from my gmail account, but when I go on the pc to look at contacts nothing is there. I imported the contacts from my sim card to my gmail account.

Comment: By saying pc what do you mean? You mean you reach your gmail account via a browser?